# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Voter -> Number]:

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting this error. I don't know why it is asking me to inject my voter model to 'Number', and I don't even know what 'Number' is, as there is no component or model named 'Number' in my project.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Voter -> Number]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Voter -> Number]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for Number!
```

Here is my app.module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// import { Voter } from './evoting/model.module';
import { EvotingModule } from './evoting/evoting.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    EvotingModule


  ],
  providers: [],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my Voter module

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'},)
export class Voter{
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public vin?: number,
        public city?: string,
        public password?: string,
        // public formdata?: FormData

    ){

    }

    clear(){
        this.id = null;
        this.name = this.vin = this.city = null;
        // this.formdata = null;
        this.password = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: generally static injector error comes when you define a service and inject that service    in the component and forget to add it inside the provider section of module or of component.   can you tell me about your Voter class , is it service or a normal interface.

Comment: could you show us your Voter )

Comment: I added now, can you please rectify my error.

Comment: Also I have tried adding Voter in appModule in provider section, it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have missed adding your service in Providers within your module like below:

```
  providers: [
    PartnerAccountInfoService,
    yourServiceName
  ]
```